# Fastest way to match strings with values contained in another data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

Sorry for the clunky title, I'm having trouble elegantly saying what I need to do. Here is some sample code:

```
a = c("12_36","13_47","10_55")
b = c("15_47")
c = NULL
d = c("Trader1", "Trader2", "Trader3","Trader4")
Profits = data.frame(Traders = d, Value = I(list(a,b,b,c)), 
                     Cost = I(list(b,a,c,a)), 
              Date = as.Date(c("2011-08-01",
                               "2011-08-02","2011-08-03","2011-08-04")))
Reference = data.frame(Index = rep(c(a,b), 4), 
                       MktPrice = c(1,4,5,6,
                                    2,3.5,7.0,8.574,
                                    9.2345,1.689,0.567,4.5362,
                                    2.35,7.66673,7.88893,6.1221),
                       Date = as.Date(c("2011-08-01","2011-08-01",
                                        "2011-08-01","2011-08-01",
                                        "2011-08-02","2011-08-02",
                                        "2011-08-02","2011-08-02",
                                        "2011-08-03","2011-08-03",
                                        "2011-08-03","2011-08-03",
                                        "2011-08-04","2011-08-04",
                                        "2011-08-04","2011-08-04")))
```

This creates two data frames. The first Profits contains four columns: The first contains the name of a trader in a virtual market. The second and third contain for each trader a vector of strings that represents the items they received or traded away. These strings correspond with values in Reference that contain their "market prices" for each day. The last column of profits is the date of that trade.

Now what I want to do is get the value for each item in the Value and Cost columns of Profits, 
find the corresponding market price for each item, and subtract the prices of the Value items from the prices of the Cost items and take this sum as a fifth column for Profits.

So I was wondering what the best way to go about this would be? I figure it will be some kind of nested function to go through Value and Cost and then match with Reference, but I'm not sure what (plyr?). Speed is also important as the actual data frames are both quite large. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, it' just not a good idea to store lists in a data.frame. Nothing in R nicely supports that. It would be best to de-normalize that table to make operations much nicer. Secondly, what do you plan to do with the NULL values? That would make the subtraction very difficult.

Comment: Hmm I can also have a version of the table where instead of the lists there would be another column that would identify the trade so each item would be on a line. As for the NULL values they will count as zero.

Answer (score 1):

So I modified the sample to use NA instead of NULL

```
a = c("12_36","13_47","10_55")
b = c("15_47")
c = NA
d = c("Trader1", "Trader2", "Trader3","Trader4")
Profits = data.frame(
    Traders = d, Value = I(list(a,b,b,c)), 
    Cost = I(list(b,a,c,a)), 
    Date = as.Date(c("2011-08-01",
        "2011-08-02","2011-08-03","2011-08-04"))
)
Reference = data.frame(
    Index = rep(c(a,b), 4), 
    MktPrice = c(1,4,5,6,
    2,3.5,7.0,8.574,
    9.2345,1.689,0.567,4.5362,
    2.35,7.66673,7.88893,6.1221),
    Date = as.Date(c("2011-08-01","2011-08-01",
    "2011-08-01","2011-08-01","2011-08-02",
    "2011-08-02","2011-08-02","2011-08-02",
    "2011-08-03","2011-08-03","2011-08-03",
    "2011-08-03","2011-08-04","2011-08-04",
    "2011-08-04","2011-08-04"))
)
```

And then I de-normalized Profits

```
dProfits<-do.call(rbind, lapply(seq.int(nrow(Profits)), function(i) {
    data.frame(Traders = Profits[i,1],
        Value = Profits[i,2][[1]],
        Cost = Profits[i,3][[1]],
        Date = Profits[i,4]
       ,stringsAsFactors=F)
}))
```

And then i used a standard merge-type procedure

```
mm<-merge(dProfits, Reference, 
    by.x=c("Value","Date"), by.y=c("Index","Date"))
mm<-merge(mm, Reference, , suffixes=c("",".Cost"),
    all.x=T, by.x=c("Cost","Date"), by.y=c("Index","Date"))
mm<-transform(mm,diff = MktPrice - MktPrice.Cost)
```

You'll have to see how it runs on your data. It may be possible to get better merge performance with `data.table` than a standard `data.frame`